# How to constrain template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a template that accepts only certain type parameters. For all the remain types I wish to produce a compile time error message. So I write the following

------Version 1------

```
template <typename T_,bool isError = true>
struct Error {
    static_assert(!isError, "Invalid Type");
};

template <typename T_>
struct Wrapper : Error <T_> {
private:
    T_ value_;
};

template <>
struct Wrapper<int> : Error<int, false> {
private:
    int value_;
};

int main()
{
    Wrapper<int> wi;
    Wrapper<long> wl;  // I get the Invalid Type.
}
```

Since I didn't use type parameter `T_` I've removed it and code stopped working.

------Version 2------

```
template <bool isError = true> 
struct Error {
    static_assert(!isError, "Invalid Type");
};

template <typename T_>
struct Wrapper : Error <> {
private:
    T_ value_;
};

template <>
struct Wrapper<int> : Error<false> {
private:
    int value_;
};

int main()
{
    Wrapper<int> wi;   // I get Invalid type ?????
    Wrapper<long> wl;  // I get the Invalid Type.
}
```

My questions are. Why is this happening after removing the type argument? Is this solution "clean"? Or exist better ways to achieve my intentions?

Comment: You got error even without `wi/wl`. Because `Error </*true*/>` is instantiated.

Comment: When you remove `T_` the base class `Error<>` for the primary `Wrapper` template is no longer dependent on the template parameter, so it gets instantiated without instantiating `Wrapper<T_>` itself. As Jarod points out, you'll run into the error even if you have an empty `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have:

```
template <typename T_>
struct Wrapper : Error <> {
private:
    T_ value_;
};
```

We can see that `Error<>` is fully specified (that is, all template parameters are known), unlike before where it was still dependent. Because of that, the compiler will actually go ahead and instantiate `Error<>` unconditionally, which means this code will never compile (even if `Wrapper` isn't mentioned at all). When `Error` still depended on `T`, it was a dependent type, so it was only instantiated case by case when a `Wrapper<T>` needed it.

I would probably separate out the trait a little differently:

```
template <class T>
struct my_trait : std::false_type {};

template <>
struct my_trait<int> : std::true_type {};

template <class T>
struct Wrapper {
    static_assert(my_trait<T>::value, "");
};

int main()
{
    Wrapper<int> wi;
    Wrapper<long> wl;  // I get the Invalid Type.
}
```

If you really want to reuse the error message, you can do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Error {
    static_assert(my_trait<T>::value, "Invalid Type");
};

template <class T>
struct Wrapper {
  static constexpr auto unused = Error<T>{};
};
```

Comment: Thank you. You're suggestion is clearly more readable and less verbose.

Comment: @JacintoResende Thanks. If you feel like this fully answers your question, you can accept it so that people know that this question doesn't need further answers.